# What happens when we prepend a row and column to a regular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I am working with a matrix $M \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ that has non-zero determinant. I then prepend a row and a column to $M$, where each entry is positive, so that $M$ is now $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ and looks like $$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & b^T\\ c & M \end{pmatrix}$$ where $a_{11} > 0$ and $b$ and $c$ are vectors consisting of all positive numbers. Does this matrix also have a non-zero determinant?

Comment: Take $n=1$ and let the extended matrix have all entries $=1$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391)

Comment: I found a relevant post here at this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995443/augmenting-a-matrix-with-a-column-and-a-row-what-happens-to-the-determinant

Comment: You are thinking like a programmer.  Note that you claim that $$M = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & b^T\\ c & M \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can very easily generate a counterexample.

For instance, start with the $2 \times 2$ matrix $$M = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ which has $\det M = 3 \neq 0$. Then, your $3 \times 3$ matrix is $$M' = \begin{bmatrix}? & ? & ? \\ ? & 2 & 1 \\ ? & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Can you fill in the $?$ entries with positive real numbers to make the first and second columns the same? If so, then $\det M' = 0$.

Comment: Thanks very much. If no columns are the same, is it then possible? The matrix I am working with is such that none of the ? entries in $M'$ are entries of $M$.

Comment: Columns don't necessarily have to be the same for the determinant to be zero. Even if the new column is a linear combination of the existing columns, we can have a zero determinant. Consider the example: $[[2,1,1],[4,2,1],[2,1,2]]$ where column 1 is twice column 2.